# Retrieving output from stored procedure in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, output-parameter

I am calling a stored procedure written at sql server, in my c# service. But I am again and again facing exception:

> InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code: Specified cast is not valid

Code:

```
public function(Data dt)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    string brand = dt.brand;
    cmd = new SqlCommand("execute pro100 @brand, @check", con);

    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@check", SqlDbType.Int);
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@brand", brand);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    int result = (int)cmd.Parameters["@check"].Value; // Exception is here
    con.Close();
    return result;
}
```

My stored procedure is as follows
This is the stored proc

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pro100]
@brand varchar(20), 
@check int output
as
update carlog set minex=1000 where brand=@brand;
select @check=id from carlog where brand=@brand;
return @check
```

Could someone suggest the possible solution maybe?

Comment: ignore pathetic grammatical sense.

Comment: When a cast is not valid you look at the type of the value you tried to cast to make sure it is expected. This goes for basically all invalid casts.

Comment: @NikunjVats next time please post your code instead image, because images often become unavailable when time passes

Comment: will take care @lazyberezovsky

Comment: @NikunjVats can you show how parameter `check` is defined in your stored procedure?

Comment: @NikunjVats please react to my comment and look at what `cmd.Parameters["@check"].Value` evaluates to at runtime using the debugger. You can evaluate this in the Immediate Window.

Comment: Isn't the @check output parameter maybe a bit data type? Which you have to specify and cast as boolean?

Comment: I've never seen anyone add the parameter list in the command text and also add it to the parameters collection.

Comment: Tip: `UPDATE` allows getting and setting values, e.g `update carlog set @check = id, @minex_before = minex, @minex_after = minex = 1000 where brand = @brand`.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a solution that ignores exception handling:

```
public function(Data dt)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(constring);

    cmd = new SqlCommand("pro100", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brand", dt.brand);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@check", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   
    int result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@check"].Value);
    con.Close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Use TryParse when you get that Int32 value: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I always re-use the variable that holds the parameter for `output` parameters, like this:-

```
public function(Data dt)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    string brand = dt.brand;
    cmd = new SqlCommand("execute pro100", con);

    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@check", SqlDbType.Int);
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@brand", brand);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    int? result = (int?)param.Value; // Exception was here
    con.Close();
    return result;
}
```

But you may also need to handle `null` values being returned from your stored procedure - by never returning a `null` - or by casting in C# to a type that can hold nulls (as I have above).  I also dropped the parameter list from the command text - as the parameters are being added in code to the parameter collection.